# C programming, error loop due to scanf?

Tags: c

I have question about `scanf` a string. I am completing a practice exercise on encoding a Vigenere cipher.

It is easy to solve it at other language but in C I have trouble and I don't know why it is.

This is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main()
{
    char mes[1000];
    char key[100];
    int n=strlen(mes);
    int cipher[n],i,j=0;

    printf("Enter message \n");
    scanf("%s",mes);

    printf("Enter keyword \n");
    scanf("%s",key);
    printf("len message= %d \n",strlen(mes));

    for(i=0;i<strlen(mes);++i)
    {
        mes[i]=toupper(mes[i]);
        key[j]=toupper(key[j]);
        if(j==strlen(key))
            j=0;
        cipher[i]=((mes[i]-0x41)+(key[j]-0x41)) % 26;
        printf("%c",cipher[i]+0x41);
        ++j;}
    printf("\n");
}
```

My code work well if `mes` array input is less than 16 character, but if `mes` input larger the program loop infinite. I don't know why.

If I change type of `cipher` array to char type, it seem work better, but the result still have wrong output like this:

```
Enter message 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Enter keyword 
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
len of message= 45
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE�EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEE
```

So can you explain:

1) Why my code do wrong if `cipher` array is an `int` type?

2) If `cipher` is char, the output better but why It have wrong output?

Comment: `printf("len message= %d \n",strlen(mes),strlen(key));` only has %d's for one of the values you're passing to printf.

Comment: You should also write `scanf("%999s", mes);` to avoid a buffer overflow, and similarly with `key`.  (don't use gets!)

Comment: also, `%s` stops on whitespace, if you want the person to be able to enter spaces in the message, you'll have to use a different function such as `fgets`.

Comment: Thanks guys, now I understand why my code do wrong. @Matt McNabb fgets is good choice.

Comment: Note: Rather than the magic number `0x41` consider `'A'`.  It self-documents the code better.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems:

1. Allocating memory for `cipher` doesn't work properly

   ```
   int n=strlen(mes); // mes has nothing now..so n=0! 
   int cipher[n],i,j=0;
   ```
2. Rolling back `j` should be done after increment .

Put this piece after you read both inputs..it should work for any length<100

```
 int cipher[strlen(mes)];
 for(i=0;i<strlen(mes);++i)
 {
     mes[i]=toupper(mes[i]);
     key[j]=toupper(key[j]);
     cipher[i]=((mes[i]-'A')+(key[j]-'A')) % 26; //use 'A' for better readability
     printf("%c",cipher[i]+'A');
     ++j;
     if(j==strlen(key))
         j=0;
 }
```

Comment: "//mes has nothing now..so n=0!", actually `mes` is indeterminate, so `n` could have anything.

Comment: Better to `char key[sizeof mes]; int cipher[sizeof mes];`.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, You wrote `int n=strlen(mes);` before giving any input,Now how would you determine the size of input when its still not given,See my comments in below code,

```
char mes[1000];
char key[100];
int n,i,j=0;

printf("Enter message \n");
scanf("%s",mes);
n=strlen(mes);//Determining Size of Input after giving it.....
int cipher[n];//Add This Here,Now You Create a array after Determining input size.

printf("Enter keyword \n");
scanf("%s",key);
printf("len message= %d \n",strlen(mes),strlen(key));
```

Comment: also, if you are using `gcc` then be sure to use `-std=c99` or `std=c11`. Without these flags, it does not follow standard behaviour for arrays with runtime size, weird things can happen.

Comment: Yes, that's correct,because c89 standard does not have variable length array feature and also it does not allow to declare a variable in middle of program(which i did in above code).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initiate the length of the chiper array correctly.. In your code:

```
char mes[1000];
char key[100];
int n=strlen(mes);
int cipher[n];
```

The length of chiper array here is undefined..
Unless you write something like:

```
int chiper[1000];
```

BR//Ari